# How can I push input value from a custom input component into an array in the parent component?

Tags: arrays, forms, vue.js

Have two input in the child components but focusing on the first input which **emits the eKey**. The second input which specifies the amount is working perfectly.

In the parent component I want the input value of the **first input** to pushed in the **epensesKey** array which is set in the `data()` section.

Note: The bigger picture is for me to send a `POST` request to my `Express Api` with the `expenseKey` and `expenseValue` array as a key/value pair

**Child Component**

```html
<template>
  <div class="input">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Expense"
      @input="$emit('eKey', $event.target.value)"
    />
    <input
      type="number"
      placeholder="Amount"
      @input="$emit('input', { 
        value: $event.target.value,
        id
      })"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "formInput",
  props: {
    id: Number,
    eKey: Array
  }
};
</script>
```

**Parent Component**

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>Budget Form</h1>

    <div class="form">
      <form action>
        <div class="topForm">
          <label for="monthlypay">Monthly pay</label>
          <input type="number" name="monthlypay" id="monthlypay" v-model="earnings" />
        </div>
      </form>

      <h2>Expenses</h2>
      <form-input v-for="(n,idx) in count" :key="n" :id="idx" :ekey="expensesKey"
      @ekey="ekey = $event" @input="getExpenseValue">
      </form-input>

      <button @click="addInputs">Add Expense</button>
      <button @click="deleteInputs">Delete</button>
      <button type="button" @click="submitBudget">Submt</button>

      <p>Total Monthly Income: {{ earnings }}</p>
      <p>Total Expense: {{ totalExpense }}</p>
      <p>Money left: {{ getDifference }}</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import formInput from "../components/Input.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    "form-input": formInput
  },
  name: "form",
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      earnings: "",
      expensesValue: [],
      expensesKey: [],
      totalExpense: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addInputs: function() {
      this.count++;
      this.expensesValue[this.count - 1] = 0;
    },
    deleteInputs: function() {
      this.count--;
      this.expensesValue.pop();

      this.setTotalExpense();
    },
     getExpenseValue(data) {
      this.expensesValue[data.id] = parseInt(data.value, 10) || 0;
      this.setTotalExpense();
    },
    setTotalExpense() {
      console.log(this.expensesValue);

      this.totalExpense = this.expensesValue.reduce((sum, val) => {
        return sum + val;
      }, 0);
    },
    submitBudget() {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/budget", {
          earning: this.earnings,
          expenses: this.expensesKey
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error(e);
        });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getDifference() {
      return this.earnings - this.totalExpense;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: @T.Short let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the parent you can do like so:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Budget Form</h1>

    <div class="form">
      <form action>
        <div class="topForm">
          <label for="monthlypay">Monthly pay</label>
          <input type="number" name="monthlypay" id="monthlypay" v-model="earnings">
        </div>
      </form>

      <h2>Expenses</h2>
      <form-input
        v-for="(n,idx) in count"
        :key="n"
        :id="idx"
        :e-key="expensesKey"
        @eKey="setExpenseKey"
        @input="getExpenseValue"
      ></form-input>

      <button @click="addInputs">Add Expense</button>
      <button @click="deleteInputs">Delete</button>
      <button type="button" @click="submitBudget">Submt</button>

      <p>Total Monthly Income: {{ earnings }}</p>
      <p>Total Expense: {{ totalExpense }}</p>
      <p>Money left: {{ getDifference }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import formInput from "./components/Input.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    "form-input": formInput
  },
  name: "form",
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      earnings: "",
      expensesValue: [],
      expensesKey: [],
      totalExpense: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addInputs: function() {
      this.count++;
      this.expensesValue[this.count - 1] = 0;
      this.expensesKey[this.count - 1] = "default";
    },
    deleteInputs: function() {
      if (this.count < 1) {
        return;
      }

      this.count--;
      this.expensesValue.pop();
      this.expensesKey.pop();

      this.setTotalExpense();
    },
    getExpenseValue(data) {
      this.expensesValue[data.id] = parseInt(data.value, 10) || 0;
      this.setTotalExpense();
    },
    setExpenseKey(data) {
      this.expensesKey[data.id] = data.value || "default";
    },
    setTotalExpense() {
      console.log(this.expensesValue);

      this.totalExpense = this.expensesValue.reduce((sum, val) => {
        return sum + val;
      }, 0);
    },
    mergeKeyAndValue() {
      return this.expensesKey.reduce((acc, key, index) => {
        return [...acc, { [key]: this.expensesValue[index] }];
      }, []);
    },
    submitBudget() {
      const expenses = this.mergeKeyAndValue();

      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/budget", {
          earning: this.earnings,
          expenses
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error(e);
        });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getDifference() {
      return this.earnings - this.totalExpense;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And in the child, you can do like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="input">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Expense"
      @input="$emit('eKey', {
        value: $event.target.value,
        id
      })"
    >
    <input
      type="number"
      placeholder="Amount"
      @input="$emit('input', { 
        value: $event.target.value,
        id
      })"
    >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "formInput",
  props: {
    id: Number,
    eKey: Array
  }
};
</script>
```

Note, I also added a function that will pair the `key` and `values` together before posting the data. (I also added some other minor improvements).

You may want to adjust some things to suit your needs.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hey it work! Thanks You! You got some serious skills.  I was wondering is there any documentation on the way you use the arrays.  For instance in addInput  method this.expensesValue[this.count - 1] or getExpenseValue method this.expensesValue[data.id]